I want to consolidate th .xls files
I have a .xls file for each day of the year from 1955 to 2023. The file naming is like: day_1955_1.tif.xls, day_1955_2.tif.xls....so on,  365 files for non leap years and 366 days files for leap years. In naming convention 1955_1, 1955_2, 1955 is the year, and 1, 2 represent day 1(January 1, 1955) and day 2 (january 2).
In these files, I have several columns, but I want to extract only two columns named GROUPED and MEAN.`
Then, I want to consolidate these files such that separate columns represent MEAN temperature values for a day of a year, GROUPED names should be rowwise only because it is same in all files, and then the column name should include both year and day; this information can be extracted from the file name (Meaning the data should be column-wise).
Then I want to save it
Further, I want to aggregate this data yearly for my GROUPED region. The year should also be column-wise.
I tried running the code, but it is not coming in the correct format. Please provide some help in this regard. I have been trying hard since this morning, but I cannot organize and aggregate the data.
I am not able to attach the code here, as it showing some syntex error. Please try to help from the information i have provided in the text.

Post your attempted code, it's easier to help you with it.

If I understand correctly in the absence of example data files, code, or expected output, here is some code that generates example .xls files, reads them in, and averages the mean column by year and group.
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate) # check for leap years during data generation
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
library(xlsx)

set.seed(42)

# generate example files
tibble(year = 1955:2023) |>
  pmap_dfr(function(year) {
    day <- if(leap_year(year)) 1:366 else 1:365
    tibble(year, day)
  }) |>
  pwalk(function(year, day) {
    write.xlsx(
      tibble(grouped = LETTERS[1:5], mean = rnorm(5)), 
      sprintf("day_%i_%i.tif.xls", year, day)
    )
  })



# read and stack files
pattern <- "day_(\\d{4})_(\\d+).tif.xls"

data <- tibble(filename = list.files(".", pattern)) |> # "." represents the current working directory
  pmap_dfr(function(filename) {
    read.xlsx(filename, 1) |>
      mutate(
        year = str_extract(filename, pattern, 1), 
        day = str_extract(filename, pattern, 2)
      ) |>
      select(year, day, grouped, mean)
  })



# summarize by year and group
data |>
  summarise(mean = mean(mean), .by = c(year, grouped))
#>    year grouped         mean
#> 1  1955       A  0.632416966
#> 2  1955       B  0.473411913
#> 3  1955       C  0.134234686
#> 4  1955       D  1.325643159
#> 5  1955       E  0.170777112
#> 6  1956       A  0.005478741
#> 7  1956       B  0.010869845
#> 8  1956       C -0.047070370
#> 9  1956       D -0.021058965
#> 10 1956       E -0.011568942

Created on 2024-05-28 with reprex v2.1.0
